# How to remove or change a player's score from Leaderboard?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have been trying to find a way to remove my fake score from my app's Leaderboard. I can't reset it because a lot of users have already connected to it. I found a way to do it: https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide

But I can't understand how to use it. Access token and all that just confused me. Any help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a one-time thing, I suggest you go to Google's [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and try to do what is documented in the link you provided.

Step-by-step instructions:

1. Open [Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/);
2. In Step 1, paste `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games` in the "Input your own scope" text box.
3. Click **Authorize APIs**. You will be taken to a Google OAuth2 login page.
4. Log into your Google account that registered your game and **Allow** what is being requested.
5. In Step 2, click on **Exchange authorization code for tokens**.
   The previous step gave you a permanent **Authorization code**, this one is giving you two new tokens: the **Refresh token** and the **Access token**.
6. In Step 3, customize the POST request with the parameters and URL documented in the link you provided. You will see the live response from the server.

**Note:** this is standard OAuth2 authentication.

- The user needs to interactively allow the application so it will generate an Authorization code, that will work forever (or until it is re-allowed).
- The refresh token is requested using the authorization code, and is also permanent (until it is requested again).
- The access token expires in one hour, and it is requested using the Refresh token.

**Basically all these levels exist for security reasons.**
You don't have to provide anyone your authorization code, only the refresh token. If some unwanted person gets access to the refresh token, you can invalidate it by requesting a new one using your secret authorization code, without having to ask for the user's permission interactively again.

Comment: I get this error when I submit request: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Google Play Game Services Management API has not been used in project 407408718192 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gamesManagement/overview?project=407408718192 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
  }
} I went to the link but Enable button is not working.

Comment: I see. Have you selected your project in the dropdown menu in the top right? Otherwise the button will be enabled but nothing will happen if you click it.

Comment: When I selected my project, it automatically enabled. Then I noticed that when I select my project the value of GET parameter "project" changes from 407408718192 to my project's name.

Comment: I believe the playground can't help you do that in this case. Take a good look at the interactions it is doing to get you the tokens you need, but you might need to request authorization for your project. This code `407408718192`, is possibly from the project used by the OAuth2 playground. You may need to implement OAuth2 in your own project, if the playground doesn't have it by default. Just to clarify: when POSTing to the API, you provided your project name as the `applicationId` parameter, right?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be like this "project-name-numbers", right?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it should be it, since it's unique. If it's not working, then it's most likely because Google hasn't enabled this API in the project used by the Playground. If that's the case, you will have to mimic what the playground does in your own environment.

Comment: @PauloAvelar I have the same issue. I tried all possibilities! I can't see any project selection drop down. Even I entered project id but doesn't seems to be working. getting same error as Trondro Mulligan.